# bootstrap/javascript dropdown menu not working on heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I have and app that functions fine on my local machine, however, when i deploy it to heroku the dropdown menu on the navbar refuses to work... here is the code for the dropdown

```js
 <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Learning Wellness <span class="caret"></span> </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><% yield (:exercise)%><%= link_to "Exercise", exercise_path%></li>
          <li><% yield (:eating_healthy)%><%= link_to "Eating Healthy", eating_healthy_path%></li>
          <li><% yield (:safety)%><%= link_to "Safety", safety_path%></li>
          <li><% yield (:health_awareness)%><%= link_to "Health & Awareness", health_awareness_path%></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
      </script>
```

I have already set all of the assets to precompile, and I have tried doing it by hand. Not sure why it isn't working

EDIT:

application.js

```js
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.slick
//= require initialize
```

Answer (score 0):

you nee to add the document.ready function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
```

instead of

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

Regards!

Comment: added the code, pushed to Heroku, still no cigar :/

Comment: I suppose that you have included the jquery and bootstrap js libraries.

Comment: yup, I added a pic to my original post